# How to add if condition to $(window).resize event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I m trying to make all embedded videos responsive since I couldn't find a good solution to make a video responsive using bootstrap 3. Using the below code I can make any video responsive. But I want to add If condition to the below code so that if window is resized, still the code does the job.

my jquery code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function show(){
  var containerWidth = $(".col-video").width();
  $('iframe').each(function(){ 
   var iframeWidth = $(this).attr("width");
   var iframeHeight = $(this).attr("height");
      var flag = containerWidth / iframeWidth;
      var newHeight = iframeHeight * flag;
   $(this).attr("width", "100%");
   $(this).attr("height", newHeight);
  });
  $('video').each(function(){ 
   var videoWidth = $(this).attr("width");
   var videoHeight = $(this).attr("height");
      var flag = containerWidth / videoWidth;
      var newHeight = videoHeight * flag;
   $(this).attr("width", "100%");
   $(this).attr("height", newHeight);
  });
 }
 show();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-video">
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kIsscNG9Q54" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fskillinprogramming%2Fvideos%2F1356766841067995%2F&show_text=0&width=400" width="400" height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
          <video src="video.mp4" controls></video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your code in the window resize event, since the event fires continously you can use a debounce function, something like:

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    show();
}, 250);

$(window).on('resize', myEfficientFn);

// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kbyevc00/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).resize()` inside your `$(document).ready()`.

The final should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $(window).resize(function () {
  (function show() {
      var containerWidth = $(".col-video").width();
        $('iframe').each(function(){ 
            var iframeWidth = $(this).attr("width");
            var iframeHeight = $(this).attr("height");
            var flag = containerWidth / iframeWidth;
            var newHeight = iframeHeight * flag;
            $(this).attr("width", "100%");
            $(this).attr("height", newHeight);
        });
        $('video').each(function(){ 
            var videoWidth = $(this).attr("width");
            var videoHeight = $(this).attr("height");
            var flag = containerWidth / videoWidth;
            var newHeight = videoHeight * flag;
            $(this).attr("width", "100%");
            $(this).attr("height", newHeight);
        });
  })();

 )};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way of doing this would be to add a wrapper around each video and adding `height:0` and `padding-bottom:56.25%;` to create a responsive div based on an aspect ratio and then absolute positioning the videos inside the wrapper. The padding bottom can be any percentage in the CSS because the JS will be adjusting in the next step anyway.

Then on page load you can calculate each videos percentage based aspect ratio and apply it to the bottom padding of the parent wrapper.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('iframe, video').each(function(){ 
    var iframeWidth = $(this).attr("width");
    var iframeHeight = $(this).attr("height");
    // calulate aspect ratio and convert to percentage
    var output = ((Math.round(iframeHeight) / Math.round(iframeWidth)) * 100).toFixed(2);
    // apply videos percentage based aspect radio to the padding bottom of the parent wrapper
    $(this).parent().css("padding-bottom", output + "%");
  });
});
```

```css
/* responsive div with 16:9 apsect ratio */
.videoWrapper {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.videoWrapper video, .videoWrapper iframe {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-video">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <div class="videoWrapper">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kIsscNG9Q54" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="videoWrapper">
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fskillinprogramming%2Fvideos%2F1356766841067995%2F&show_text=0&width=400" width="400" height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="videoWrapper">
       <video src="video.mp4" controls></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```